# automatically determine number of clusters k-means

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, k-means, rapidminer

I want to build a cluster model in rapid miner that can define the number of clusters automatically and then continue to the k-means algorithm. Is there any way for determine k of clustering automatically in rapid miner?

Comment: You should ask such questions on the **rapidminer forums**, unless you mean to modify the rapdiminer source code - this site is for programming questions, not for usage questions.

Answer (score 3):

In k-means, the value of k is supplied by the user. The clusters that are produced can be assessed using a cluster validity measure (such as Davies-Bouldin) to give a score. By varying k, different cluster validity scores can be produced and the optimum score (for Davies-Bouldin a minimum) would be a candidate for the most interesting value of k. Follow the link for details on how this might be done in RapidMiner [Examples](http://rapidminernotes.blogspot.co.uk/search/label/ClusterValidity).

There are many caveats associated with this. The most important point is that a domain expert must be involved to check that the value of k and the clustering that is produced has meaning.

Answer (score 0):

One trick to determining K is to run a DBSCAN on your dataset first. Determine the number of clusters from DBSCAN, and then get the cluster centers using K-means

Here is some python code:

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN #python -m pip install scikit-learn
import cv2 as cv #python -m pip install opencv-python
import numpy as np #python -m pip install numpy
Z=np.array([0.0,1.0,0.25,0.11,0.12,0.27,0.99,1.1,0.05,0.06]) 
Z=np.unique(Z) #speed up the DBSCAN by considering only unique points
Z=Z.reshape((-1,1)).astype(np.float32)
K=int(np.max(DBSCAN(eps=0.05,min_samples=2).fit(Z).labels_))+1
criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
_,label,center=cv.kmeans(Z,K,None,criteria,10,cv.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
print(f"\nK={K}")
print("\nlabel=")
print(label)
print("\ncenter=")
print(center)
```

Output from the code:

```
K=4

label=
[[0]
 [0]
 [0]
 [3]
 [3]
 [1]
 [1]
 [2]
 [2]
 [2]]

center=
[[0.03666667]
 [0.26      ]
 [1.0300001 ]
 [0.11499999]]
```